# $|f|$ is strictly greater than some positive real number in some interval

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is nonzero. Show that there exists some interval such that $|f|>\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a strictly positive real number.

Is the following correct?

Without loss of generality, assume the function $f$ is nonnegative. Then by Riemann integrability there exists a partition $P$ such that $L(f,P)>\int_0^1 fdx-1/2(\int_0^1 fdx)$. Therefore there exists some interval such that $|f|>1/2(\int_0^1 fdx)$ throughout the interval.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $0<\left\lvert\displaystyle\int f\space dx\right\rvert\le \displaystyle\int |f|\space dx$. Now use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224799/if-f-is-continuous-nonnegative-on-a-b-show-that-int-ab-fx-dx?rq=1) to conclude the existence of $\alpha$.

Comment: Is there any problem with my proof though?

Comment: How can you assume that without loss of generality $f$ is non-negative? It can be neither. Consider the function $f:[a,b]\to[-1,1]$ defined by, $$f\begin{cases}=-1&\text{if}\space x=a\\=0&\text{if}\space x=b\\=1&\text{else}\end{cases}$$What is the value of $\displaystyle\int_{a}^b f\space dx$?

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable then so are $f^+$ and $f^-$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that $|f| $ is also integrable with a positive integral and thus the lower Darboux sums for $|f|$ converge to a positive value. It follows that there is some sub-interval where $\inf |f|$ is positive. This is essentially same as your approach but we don't need to assume non negative $f$, that role is taken by $|f|$.

Comment: Thank you but Is there anything wrong with the assumption without loss of generality?

Comment: Well... You lose generality...

Comment: @2ndaccount: The thing is that if $f$ is non-negative then $|f|=f$ and thus the proof essentially needs to deal with $|f|$ rather than $f$ so that the sign of $f$ is actually immaterial. In that sense you may say "without loss of generality". But this phrase is not used in this sense typically. Rather it is used with the justification that if the result holds for non-negative $f$ then it holds for general $f$ too.